# Problema ao usar MAP no Sass

Tags: sass

Como lançado no blog do [Sass](http://blog.sass-lang.com/posts/184094-sass-33-is-released) a partir da versão 3.3 está disponível a criação de `map` no Sass (basicamente um objeto). Estou com a seguinte versão do Sass (devidamente atualizado pelo GEM):

```
$ sass -v
Sass 3.3.5 (Maptastic Maple)
```

E com a seguinte versão do Compass:

```
$ compass -v
Compass 0.12.5 (Alnilam)
```

Até aí, beleza. Então fui criar um mapa que fica num arquivo chamado: `_palette-colors.sass` e tem o seguinte conteúdo:

```
$objeto: (key1: valor1, key2: valor2)
```

*(já testei com a sintaxe do `.scss` também)* E quando compilo recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> error sass/output/style.sass (Line 4 of sass/lib/map/_palette-color.sass: Invalid CSS after "(key1": expected ")", was ": valor1, key2:...")

Gostaria de saber se estou fazendo algo de errado ou se estou esquecendo de criar ou modificar alguma coisa antes de compilar. Dei uma pesquisada pela web e como é algo novo no Sass não achei muitas referências sobre problemas ou aplicações.

PS: Já tentei transformando as keys e/ou valores em string's e não rolou também.

Comment: Recebi de um amigo pelo skype a resposta para este problema e caso alguém passe por ele é preciso executar o seguinte comando: `gem install compass --pre` para instalar a ultima versão beta do compass.

Comment: Oi Juarez, aqui "resolvido" é uma resposta marcada como *correta*. Por favor, publique a solução como Resposta no box abaixo. Confira o guia [About].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversando com um amigo pelo skype ele me passou a solução pois já tinha passado pelo mesmo problema a pouquissimo tempo.

Basta executar o comando abaixo no seu prompt do ruby (no windows) ou no terminal no linux.

```
gem install compass --pre
```

O comando acima irá instalar uma versão Beta do compass que já suporta os mapas do sass.